# FindRoot giving false roots with Bessel Functions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have read in some places about the errors associated with FindRoot, but the closest thing I can find on this website seems to be due to the imaginary unit. I am dealing with what should be a relatively simple function for Mathematica to handle, namely a sum of Bessel functions of the first and modified first kinds. My code is

```
Zeros[z_] = (BesselJ[0, z] - BesselJ[2, z])*(3*BesselI[1, z] + 
  BesselI[3, z]) - (BesselI[0, z] + 
  BesselI[2, z])*(3*BesselJ[1, z] - BesselJ[3, z]);
FindRoot[Zeros[z]==0,{z,1}]
```

which returns 1.4371. But Zeros[1.4371]=-2.0754. I can also find roots by looking at the graph and basically bisecting by hand. My question is, should I rely on the plot, or the findroot algorithm? I am very familiar with Newton's Method (which is what I think FindRoot uses), but it does not make sense to me how it could guess such an erroneous root; this section of the plot shows none of the typical pitfalls of Newton's method. The second root on the other hand is at ~4.4, which the FindRoot algorithm finds to be 4.77493, which isn't a bad estimate given the slope of the function at this location.

So, I guess my question boils down to, should I check (and believe) the plot or the FindRoot algorithm, or perhaps neither?

Comment: What version are you using? With 9.0.1, I get something  approximately 0 for `FindRoot[Zeros[z] == 0, {z, 1}]` and `4.43216` for `FindRoot[Zeros[z] == 0, {z, 4}]`, both of which appear to be correct.

Comment: I am using 9.0.0, this may be the difference. I found both of those roots by looking at the plot. Can you do me a favor and tell me what root you find near 23? There should be one at about 23.504 according to the plot. If you get this then I will update to 9.0.1 and try again, if not, I will just stick to checking out the plot.

Comment: I get 24.5046 for that.  Can't reproduce the issue in 8.0.4 or 9.0.1.  Definitely update to 9.0.1, there have been a number of bugfixes.

Comment: Thank you, I think my question has been answered sufficiently now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have tried your code from a fresh kernel -- sometimes old definitions unexpectedly cause such problems.

I find I get the same (correct) approximate zeros from `FindRoot` in V9.0.1 and V8.0.4.  Here's a nice way to get a bunch of zeros using a quick but somewhat sloppy `NDSolve` to seed `FindRoot`.  (It misses the easy one, `z -> 0`, though because `WhenEvent` requires a zero-*crossing*.)

```
(zeros = First @ Last @ Reap @ Quiet @ NDSolve[
   {y'[x] == Zeros'[x], y[0] == Zeros[0], 
    WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[FindRoot[Zeros[z], {z, x}]]]}, 
   y, {x, 0, 40}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.075423,
    {{z -> 4.43216}, {z -> 7.68556}, {z -> 10.8744}, {z -> 14.0424},
     {z -> 17.2009}, {z -> 20.3543}, {z -> 23.5046}, {z -> 26.6528},
     {z -> 29.7997}, {z -> 32.9456}, {z -> 36.0907}, {z -> 39.2353}}} *)

Plot[Zeros[z]/E^z, {z, 0, 40},
  Mesh -> {z /. zeros}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize@Medium, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also use just `NDSolve`, but it's slower:

```
(zeros = First @ Last @ Reap @ Quiet @ NDSolve[
   {y'[x] == Zeros'[x], y[0] == Zeros[0], 
    WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[{z -> x}]]}, 
   y, {x, -1, 40}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.302113,
    {{z -> 4.43216}, {z -> 7.68556}, {z -> 10.8744}, {z -> 14.0424},
     {z -> 17.2009}, {z -> 20.3543}, {z -> 23.5046}, {z -> 26.6528},
     {z -> 29.7997}, {z -> 32.9456}, {z -> 36.0907}, {z -> 39.2353}}} *)
```

Comment: Nice! Why do you use 1 for AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Lowering `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` makes `NDSolve` faster, because the algorithm terminates when the goals are achieve. If you're is going to post-process with `FindRoot`, you use `NDSolve` only to approximate the roots close enough that `FindRoot` converges quickly.  It's possible for errors to accumulate so that the estimates given by `NDSolve` miss a root, in which case I would increase them.

Comment: Thank you, I think my answer has been answered sufficiently now.