# NDSolve + FindRoot for Bessel Zeros

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to use a solution given by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36997/findroot-giving-false-roots-with-bessel-functions):

```
Zeros[z_] = (BesselJ[0, z] - BesselJ[2, z])*(3*BesselI[1, z] + 
  BesselI[3, z]) - (BesselI[0, z] + 
  BesselI[2, z])*(3*BesselJ[1, z] - BesselJ[3, z]);

(zeros = First @ Last @ Reap @ Quiet @ NDSolve[
   {y'[x] == Zeros'[x], y[0] == Zeros[0], 
    WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[FindRoot[Zeros[z], {z, x}]]]}, 
   y, {x, 0, 40}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

-- to find roots for my equation:

$$
J_1(a/z)\, Y_0(b/z)-J_0(a/z)\,Y_1(b/z)=0, \quad a=10, \;b=1,
$$

but get an error

```
First::first: "{} has a length of zero and no first element."
```

The problem is that "y(x)=0" event doesn't happen. I understand that the functions are quite different, so I perform the following:

$$
J_1(a/z)\; Y_0(b/z)-J_0(a/z)\; Y_1(b/z)=0 \rightarrow\\
\rightarrow \left( J_1(a\tilde z)\; Y_0(b\tilde z)-J_0(a\tilde z)\; Y_1(b\tilde z) \right)\; e^{-100/\tilde z}=0, ~\tilde z = 1/z
$$

to make my function to be more like the original one, but still get the error. Could anyone help, please?

My code (I mean, the original code with my function) is below.

```
Sigma = 1;
xi1 = 10;
Zeros[z_] = 
  (BesselJ[1, xi1*z]*BesselY[0, Sigma*z] - 
   BesselJ[0, Sigma*z]*BesselY[1, xi1*z])*Exp[-100/z];
(zeros = First@
Last@Reap@
  Quiet@NDSolve[{y'[x] == Zeros'[x], y[0] == Zeros[0], 
 WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[FindRoot[Zeros[z], {z, x}]]]}, 
y, {x, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: The first code you posted works OK here. Try restarting Mathematica. If it doesn't work, post the version of Mathematica you're using

Comment: @belisarius First code works good. The problem is that I can't get it working with another function, even if I make that function look like the first one (more or less). See second code. My version of Mathematica is 9.0.1.0, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Here's the code.

```
xi1 = 10;
Sigma = 1;
f3[z_] = BesselJ[1, xi1/z]*BesselY[0, Sigma/z] - 
   BesselJ[0, Sigma/z]*BesselY[1, xi1/z];

Timing[roots3 = 
Reap[First[
 NDSolve[{x'[z] == f3'[z], x[1] == f3[1]}, {x}, {z, 15, 0.1}, 
  Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> x[z], 
    "EventAction" :> Sow[z]}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001, 
  MaxSteps -> 1000000]]][[2, 1]]]
```

And

```
f3 /@ roots3
```

shows that the roots are quite accurate. Sure it doesn't find all the roots in the interval and skips some of them, but one can easily increase the accuracy.

Note: I used my initial function.