# Finding Root of BesselJ

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, implementation-details

When I work on some physical problem I needed to know how to get all of first 100 roots of `BesselJ[n,x]` function -which is a quasi periodic function-, as a List. I tried this code:

```
FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, {2, 5, 8, 11, 14}}]

{x -> {2.40483, 5.52008, 8.65373, 11.7915, 14.9309}}
```

but it's so terrible because you need firstly to know the approximation root as argument, and it'll give you the exact root.

I ask if there any other direct methods.

***Update from [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/finding-root-of-besselj#comment462579_176257):***

Yeah [there is `BesselJZero[]`,] but I want to know what is the code inside this `BesselJZero[]`. I mean how I can construct it by myself?

*[Edit notice: I (Michael E2) discovered the answer to this question, which now sits in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/finding-root-of-besselj#comment462722_176257). I'd be happy to post the comment as an answer if the community thinks this question should be reopened.]*

Comment: Have you seen `BesselJZero[]`? There's a link to it near the bottom of the doc page for `BesselJ` under "See Also".

Comment: Yeah but  i want to know what is the code inside this  `BesselJZero[]` i mean how i can construct it by myself ?

Comment: There are some unsatisfying hints in the "Related Links" of the doc page for `BesselJZero`, which suggest they might use "use series and asymptotic expansions."

Comment: For a more complicated example involving roots of combinations of Bessel functions, see e.g. [Labeling solutions of an Eigenvalue equation involving Bessel functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103176/245). In my answer to that question, I use `FindRoot` with starting values determined by the (asymptotic) WKB approximation to find the roots - giving an improved version of `BesselJYJYZeros`.

Comment: You may also be interested in the numerical approaches discussed in [Find roots of a function involving Bessel functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59007/245)

Comment: Before `BesselJZero` was introduced in V6, there was a package ``NumericalMath`BesselZeros` ``, available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6777/), that contains code for `BesselJZero`. I don't know if it is the same as the current implementation. It cites [Abramovitz & Stegun 9.5.12](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_371.htm), which is the same as [DLMF 10.21.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21.E19). You can inspect the code yourself. The main function is `bz[]`, which handles the zeros of both the $J$ and the $Y$ functions.

Comment: thank you Mr @MichaelE2

Answer (score 6):

The asymptotic form for $x\rightarrow\infty$ of $J_0(x)$ is $\sqrt{2/(\pi *x)} {\rm Cos}[x-\pi/4]$, with zeros at $x=(k-1/4)\pi$, for $k=1,2,3,...$. These values of $x$ approximate the zeros quite well.

If you want to use `FindRoot` so you "can construct it by myself", try

```
Table[FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, (k - 1/4) Pi}], {k, 1, 100}]
```

where `k` is the index of the root. The result is the same as

```
BesselJZero[0, Range[1.,100.]]
```

The asymptotic form for  $J_n(x)$ is $\sqrt{2/(\pi *x)} {\rm Cos}[x-\pi/4-n \pi/2]$.

Comment: The asymptotic form starts to give poor starting points for the roots for small `k` when the order `n` is greater than or equal to `6`.

Answer (score 6):

A more general result than that provided by KennyColnago

The built-in `BesselJZero[n, k]`

```
Grid[tab = Table[{n, k, BesselJZero[n, k] // N}, {n, 0, 3}, {k, 3}]]
```

[image]

While this is not the code that Mathematica uses, you can generate your own `BesselJZero[n, k]` values using `FindRoot`

```
Grid[tab2 = Table[
   {n, k, x /. FindRoot[BesselJ[n, x] == 0, {x, (2 k + 1) (2 n + 9)/8}]},
   {n, 0, 3}, {k, 3}]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
tab - tab2 // Chop

(* {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, @Bob Hanlon, but `{x, (2 k + 1) (2 n + 9)/8} ` are very bad starting values. Regard `tab1 = Flatten[
   Table[{n, k, BesselJZero[n, k] // N}, {n, 0, 20}, {k, 100}], 1]; ` and `tab2 = Flatten[
   Table[{0, 0, 
     x /. First@
       FindRoot[BesselJ[n, x] == 0, {x, (2 k + 1) (2 n + 9)/8}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 20]}, {n, 0, 20}, {k, 100}], 1]; `  to see, nearly all but the first 3 zeros are wrong.  `ListPointPlot3D[tab1 - tab2, PlotRange -> {-1000, 0}] ` .

Answer (score 2):

An easy straightforward approach

```
NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 <= x <= 50}, x]
(*{{x -> 2.40483}, {x -> 5.52008}, {x -> 8.65373}, {x -> 11.7915}, 
{x ->14.9309}, {x -> 18.0711}, {x -> 21.2116}, {x -> 24.3525}, 
{x ->27.4935},{x  -> 30.6346}, {x -> 33.7758}, {x -> 36.9171}, 
{x ->40.0584}, {x -> 43.1998}, {x -> 46.3412}, {x -> 49.4826}}*)
```

evaluates all roots in the given range.

Unfortunately the possible range seems to be restricted `x<55.7655` perhaps for numerical reasons. Adapting WorkingPrecision might help...

Comment: In MMA Version 8.0, x is not restricted at all.

Comment: If you try `NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 50 <= x <= 100}, x]` MMA 11.0.1.0 gives only two solutions `{{x -> 52.6241}, {x -> 55.7655}}` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: This is a real setback compared to Version 8, which gives all.

Comment: `NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 50 <= x <= 100}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 32]` gives all roots.