# Trouble with Newton-Raphson Method in Bessel zeros

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I'm newbie here, and using Mathematica for two weeks, so, anyone can help me with this? I tried using the `Findroot` command but I don't get it. Thanks in advance guys.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/finding-root-of-besselj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] := BesselJ[0, x]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 15},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{BesselJZero[0, #], 0}], BesselJZero[0, #] // N] & /@
    Range[5]}]
```

[image]

To see the progressive estimates using Newton-Raphson, use [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html)

```
(sol1a = Table[
    FixedPointList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0], {x0, 3., 15, 3}]) // Column
```

[image]

To see just the final values use [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html)

```
(sol1b = Table[FixedPoint[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0], {x0, 3., 15, 3}])

(* {2.40483, 5.52008, 8.65373, 11.7915, 14.9309} *)
```

Alternatively, using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) or [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)

```
(sol2a = Table[
    NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, 10], {x0, 3., 15., 3.}]) // Column
```

[image]

```
(sol2b = Table[Nest[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, 10], {x0, 3., 15., 3.}])

(* {2.40483, 5.52008, 8.65373, 11.7915, 14.9309} *)
```

Using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
sol3 = x /. FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ Range[3., 15, 3]

(* {2.40483, 5.52008, 8.65373, 11.7915, 14.9309} *)
```

Using [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
sol4 = x /. NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x] == 0, 0 < x < 15}, x]

(* {2.40483, 5.52008, 8.65373, 11.7915, 14.9309} *)
```

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) give the solution in terms of [`BesselJZero`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html)

```
x /. Solve[{BesselJ[0, x] == 0, 0 < x < 15}, x]

(* {BesselJZero[0, 1], BesselJZero[0, 2], BesselJZero[0, 3], BesselJZero[0, 4], 
 BesselJZero[0, 5]} *)

x /. {ToRules[Reduce[{BesselJ[0, x] == 0, 0 < x < 15}, x]]}

(* {BesselJZero[0, 1], BesselJZero[0, 2], BesselJZero[0, 3], BesselJZero[0, 4], 
 BesselJZero[0, 5]} *)
```

Comparing with the `BesselJZero` values

```
bjz = BesselJZero[0, #] & /@ Range[5];

sol1a[[All, -1]] == sol1b == sol2a[[All, -1]] == sol2b == sol3 == sol4 == bjz

(* True *)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I do not have a formula, that's what I do not understand, how do I apply it?

Comment: You gave Newton-Raphson formula, i.e., `x[i+1] == x[i] - f[x[i]]/f'[x[i]]`. When written as a [`pure function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) the RHS is `# - f[#]/f'[#] &`. `FixedPointList` and `FixedPoint` iterate this pure function until the results converge and stops automatically. `NestList` and `Nest` iterates the pure function a specified number of times. For a sufficiently large number of specified iterations the result will converge to the fixed point. In all of these cases a starting value (x[0]) must be specified that is in the region of the desired root.

Comment: thanks Bob, Now I understand it all

Answer (score 0):

```
  f[x_] := BesselJ[0, x]    
    x[0] = 1.;(*initial point*)(*different initial point converge to different root*)
    Table[x[i + 1] = x[i] - f[x[i]]/f'[x[i]]; x[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

> {1., 2.73889, 2.36779, 2.40456, 2.40483, 2.40483, 2.40483, 2.40483,2.40483, 2.40483, 2.40483}

```
  x[0] = 5.;(*initial point*)
    Table[x[i + 1] = x[i] - f[x[i]]/f'[x[i]]; x[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

> {5., 5.54215, 5.52003, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008, 5.52008}

Comment: thank you this was very helpful :)